# calling unmanaged dll function that returns an array of struct using C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct

I am having an unmanaged dll written using C++. I am able to call some functions easily from my C# application. But one function make me suffer :)

### C++

The problem is in the log parameter. It should be reflected as an array of the `Data_Struct` type:

```
typedef struct
{
unsigned int    id;
unsigned short  year;
unsigned char   month;
unsigned char   day;
unsigned char   hour;
unsigned char   min;
unsigned char   sec;
unsigned char   status; 
}Data_Struct;

int Read_Stored_Data(HUNIT pUnitHandle, int option, int updateFlag, 
                     int maxEntries, unsigned char *log)
```

### C# (my conversion)

```
public struct Data_Struct
{
    public uint id;
    public ushort year;
    public byte month;
    public byte day;
    public byte hour;
    public byte min;
    public byte sec;
    public byte status;

}

[DllImport("SData.dll", EntryPoint = "Read_Stored_Data")]
public static extern int Read_Stored_Data(int pUnitHandle, int option, 
    int updateFlag, int maxEntries, ref Data_Struct[] log);
```

Please assume that I am passing `pUnitHandle`, `option`, `updateFlag`, `maxEntries` with correct values. The problem is the last parameter (`log`):

```
Data_Struct[] logs = new Data_Struct[1000];
res = Read_Stored_Data(handle, 1, 0, 1000, ref logs); // This should work but it 
                                                      // causes the application 
                                                      // to terminate!
```

Any idea?

Comment: What happens when you call it? Unbalanced stack? `AccessViolationException`? Fails silently?

Comment: fails silently .. doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try playing with the PInvoke attributes.

Specifically, apply layout to the struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Data_Struct
{
    public uint id;
    public ushort year;
    public byte month;
    public byte day;
    public byte hour;
    public byte min;
    public byte sec;
    public byte status;
}
```

and apply a marshalling attribute to the parameter, while removing `ref`:

```
[DllImport("SData.dll", EntryPoint = "Read_Stored_Data")]
public static extern int Read_Stored_Data(int pUnitHandle, int option,
    int updateFlag, int maxEntries, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), Out()] Data_Struct[] log);
```

See if that helps, adjust accordingly.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Even though [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
is not required.

Comment: again got trapped after changing the struct as follows: